# Did I determine the pronunciation of 人口 correctly?

Tags: kanji, readings, onyomi

On a Kanji exercise, I was told to find how 人口 is read.

Because the kanji are a word, I used the on-yomi of both and I answered "にんこう".

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, 人口 is read じんこう (look the word up in a dictionary). Some *kanji* have more than one *on'yomi*. This is due to the fact that they were imported from different areas and/or in different eras from China.

For 人, ジン is a *kan'on* (漢音) reading and ニン is a *goon* (呉音) reading.

In compound words, usually both have the same type of *on'yomi*. Here, both ジン and コウ are *kan'on* readings. (口 also has the different *jōyō* reading, namely the *on'yomi* ク, which is a *goon* reading.)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that 人口 is a word (meaning "population"), but it is pronounced じんこう.
In this instance, both kanji are using on-yomi, which is commonly used in compounds that linguistically originate from Japanese rather than Chinese.

Dictionary entry from JDIC is here. You can easily find pronunciation(s) in dictionary entries.
http://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&q=1367300